# How can I trigger multiple Gitlab pipeline from monorepo?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, devops

I have a microservices project repo that is pretty much same as the very famous example project [Spring Petclinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-microservices)

I am trying to have a "master pipeline" and "service pipelines". An example:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target/

before_script:
  - chmod +x mvnw

include:
  - local: spring-petclinic-admin-server/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-visits-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-vets-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-discovery-server/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-customers-service/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-config-server/.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: spring-petclinic-api-gateway/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

spring-petclinic-admin-server/.gitlab-ci.yml (altered for each microservices 7 times):

```
build:
  script:
    - ./mvnw $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -PbuildDocker
  only:
    changes:
      - "spring-petclinic-spring-petclinic-admin-server/**/*"

test:
  script:
    - ./mvnw $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  only:
    changes:
      - "spring-petclinic-spring-petclinic-admin-server/**/*"
```

When I did a mock edit and commited to repo to trigger the pipeline, it commited but didn't trigger the pipeline, no jobs are running etc.

Also, is there a better way to run a specific microservice's pipeline without making changes? I always have to `git reset --hard` after doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In principle your approach should be working fine. I have a comparable setup in several of my mono repos.

I would recommend migrating to the `rules` keyword. That seems to be more reliable and `only` has been depreciated for a while now.

I have defined a template and set a variable `$PROJECT_NAME` in each job to save duplicating the rules block.

```yaml
.template:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ "pipeline|trigger|web" && $TRIGGER_PROJECT == $PROJECT_NAME
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE !~ "schedule|pipeline|trigger|web"
          changes:
            - ${PROJECT_NAME}/**/*

myproject:
    extends: [ .template ]
    variables:
        PROJECT_NAME: myproject
    script:
         - ...
```

Setting the variable `$TRIGGER_PROJECT` when manually starting the job or using the trigger API then allows to specifically ensure a certain project pipeline is run. With [`variables:options`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variablesoptions) this can be made even more comfortable in the UI.

Edit: the solution involves quite a couple of folders/files. Have a look at my MWE here: https://gitlab.com/mpolitze/so-77892260

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I honestly, try to make your suggestion work and it does seem straightforward but for some reason I still don't have an implementation that works. Can you elaborate your answer a bit with where is this code supposed to go and is it a new file or something?

Comment: I set up a MWE for you to look at: https://gitlab.com/mpolitze/so-77892260. If you want you can make a fork to test out the "Run Pipeline" feature.